# Why does the ng-view method in the angular-seed project only work for index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am exploring the angular-seed structure and tried to create another html page called secure.html to bootstrap the same ng-view as the index.html, but for some reason it only works on index.html

The HTML in secure.html is the exact same as index.html (I declared ng-app and I also load the same js files.) The two html files are also on the same directory level.

Comment: See browser developer console log to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

> ngView is a directive that complements the $route service by including
>   the rendered template of the current route into the main layout
>   (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included
>   view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route
>   service.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView